# FCKEditor or CKEditor Plugin where some of the text is un-modifiable

Tags: javascript, jsp, ckeditor, fckeditor

I am using FCKEditor in my project and need some of the text to be un-modifiable in that.
I am thinking like create some plugin which will make some specific tag like `<a href...>` tag to be Un-modifiable.

See in below image... Like `EBL:{Blood Loss:minimal}`  and `Fluids {Fluids: none}` is Un-modifyable part in HTML. I mean kind of these. Some part of Text is not modifiable. Any one can give me any hint for any plugin like that... Thanks...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's official placeholder plugin for CKEditor. You can check it here http://nightly.ckeditor.com/7597/_samples/placeholder.html It should be appropriate to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. and it's relevant to my need. Thanks again.